# How can I manipulate elements from text file in a list?

Tags: python, text-files, typeerror

So I have made a code that extracts information from a text file. It contains temperatures of a given month, and its supposed to store it in a list. As I print it, it's correct. Furthermore I need to actually use these extracted numbers to calculate the mean, max and min etc... but it won't work. I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list' when trying for example:

```
sum(oct_1945)/len(oct_1945)
```

also:

```
mean_1945=np.mean(oct_1945)
```

but I just get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

My full code and print statement is as following:

```
#xtract data for 1945 temperatures
def extract_data(temp_oct_1945):
    infile = open('temp_oct_1945.txt', 'r') #Open temps for 1945
    infile.readline() #skip first line
    oct_1945=[] #empty ist for temps
    for line in infile:
        numbers=line.split()
        oct_1945.append(numbers)
    infile.close()
    return oct_1945

oct_1945=extract_data('temp_oct_1945.txt')#define oct_1945


def extract_data(temp_oct_2014):
    infile = open('temp_oct_2014.txt', 'r') #Open temps for 2014
    infile.readline() #skip first line
    oct_2014=[] #empty ist for temps
    for line in infile:
        numbers=line.split()
        oct_2014.append(numbers)
    infile.close()
    return oct_2014

oct_2014=extract_data('temp_oct_2014.txt')#define oct_1945

#print statements
"""
1945 temperatures [['7.2', '8.1', '8.9', '11.6', '7.7', '8.7', '6.9'], 
                   ['5.4', '8.8', '8.9', '3.7', '3.3', '5.2', '9.6'], 
                   ['10.8', '5.0', '5.4', '9.5', '5.3', '5.8', '2.3'], 
                   ['4.1', '6.6', '8.2', '6.1', '8.9', '6.6', '4.1'], 
                   ['2.8', '2.1', '4.1']]
2014 temperatures [['9.8', '11.6', '11.5', '13.3', '12.6', '10.3', '7.5'], 
                   ['9.3', '10.3', '10.3', '8.4', '8.8', '5.0', '5.8'], 
                   ['6.8', '2.3', '3.5', '7.9', '11.8', '10.7', '9.0'], 
                   ['5.8', '6.8', '11.7', '10.6', '11.7', '13.1', '13.6'],
                   ['8.0', '3.5', '3.2']]
"""
```

Comment: Your output is a list of lists. When you line.split() it's creating a list of elements. You need to join them back into a string before appending. Or create a pandas dataframe on the data.

Comment: Uhh i dont understand how do i do it

Comment: Is each value a new column or is each value part of one column? What's your desired outcome for the data? Depending on what you want to do, you could just change your .append to .extend.

Comment: I want to use the data to store it in list and then use the numbers in the list to calculate the mean, max temperature etc... what it seems is that each line in the text document is a list in a nested list of columns instead of just a list of all the values. How would i do that? The document for ex. Has following:

Comment: 10 20 30 40 50 ... etc consisting of four columns or rows or whatever. And i want to store every single number into one list from the txt file and then use the numbers in that list in my python program

Comment: Then all you have to do is change .append(numbers) to .extend(numbers). Then your data are in strings, so you need to convert them to floats, which can be done in a list comprehension [float(x) for x in oct_2014] for example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have two functions that are essentially identical and share the same name. What we can do is have a single function that we pass the filename to. What we do is read the numbers as a list of strings per line, then join these together and map all entries of the list to floats and return the resulting list.

```
def extract_data(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')  # open file
    infile.readline()  # skip first line
    numbers = []  # stores numbers as strings 
    for line in infile:
        numbers += line.split()
    infile.close()
    return list(map(float, numbers))
    
 print(extract_data('temp_oct_1945.txt'))
 print(extract_data('temp_oct_2014.txt'))
```

Comment: I wouldn't covert floats to integers unless you have a good reason.

Comment: You're correct, I changed it to use float. Despite you using two separate functions they are identical other than that they open different files, you can instead just have one function which you pass the filename to.